# Connection between countable ordinals and Turing degrees

Tags: reference-request, computability-theory, computer-science, ordinal-numbers, ordinal-computability

$\omega^{CK}_1$ is the supremum of all the [recursive ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_ordinal), where an ordinal $\alpha$ is recursive if there is a computable ordering of a subset of the naturals with order type $\alpha$.

For a [Turing degree](http://if%20there%20is%20a%20computable%20ordering%20of%20a%20subset%20of%20the%20naturals%20with%20order%20type%20$%5Calpha$.) $D$, we will say that an ordinal $\alpha$ is $D$-recursive if there is a $D$-computable ordering of a subset of the naturals with order type $\alpha$. We will also say that the supremum of the $D$-recursive ordinals is $\omega^{CK}_D$.

This has some interesting properties that connects Turing degrees and countable ordinals. For example, for any countable ordinal $\alpha$ there is a Turing degree $D$ such that $\alpha$ is $D$-recursive (simply choose a ordering of the natural numbers with order type $\alpha$, and construct an oracle that computes that ordering). This in particular implies that supremum of the $\omega^{CK}_D$ over all Turing degrees $D$ is [$\omega_1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_uncountable_ordinal). Additionally, the order type of the $\omega^{CK}_D$ over all Turing degrees $D$ is also $\omega_1$. Also, for each Turing degree $D$, we can construct an ordinal notation for the ordinals $< \omega^{CK}_D$, similar to [Kleene's O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_O).

My question is, has this relationship between Turing degrees and countable ordinals been explored before?

Comment: Yes, of course this has been explored. Did you have a more specific question about it?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins is there a reference? I couldn't find any (although I probably didn't look very hard).

Comment: One quibble: I don't believe that you can in fact generalize Kleene's $\mathcal{O}$ to arbitrary Turing **degrees** - while $\mathcal{O}^X$ makes sense for any *set* $X$, I don't see any way to get a notation system which is degree-invariant. @JoelDavidHamkins Do you know if such a thing exists?

Comment: To clarify my previous comment: first, note that while $\varphi_e^X$ makes sense for $X$ a **set**, $\varphi_e^{\bf d}$ doesn't make any sense for $\bf d$ a **degree** - and in general just knowing $X\equiv_TY$ tells us nothing about the relationship between $\varphi_e^X$ and $\varphi_e^Y$. Here's a precise version of my question above: is there a $\Pi^1_1$ way to assign to each set $X$ a notation set $\mathcal{N}^X$ and a valuation map $\nu_X$ such that: $(i)$ for $X\equiv_TY$ we have $\mathcal{N}^X=\mathcal{N}^Y, \nu_X=\nu_Y$ and $(ii)$ $\sup\{\nu_X(n): n\in\mathcal{N}^X\}=\omega_1^{CK}(X)$?

Comment: Interestingly, of course the map $X\mapsto\omega_1^{CK}(X)$ *is* degree-invariant. There are a couple ways to state this: one is that $X\equiv_TY$ implies $\sup\{\mu_X(n): n\in\mathcal{O}^X\}=\sup\{\mu_Y(n): n\in\mathcal{O}^Y\}$ where $\mathcal{O}^X,\mu_X$ are the usual notation system and valuation map assigned to $X$ a la Kleene and another is that if $X\equiv_TY$ then an ordinal $\alpha$ - identified with the structure $(\alpha; <)$ - has a copy computable in $X$ iff it has a copy computable in $Y$). Lesson: when relativizing concepts, we have to be **very careful** about uniformity issues.

Comment: Noah, I agree with all your comments.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Do you happen to know if a degree-invariant notation system exists?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Couldn't you just use the axiom of choice to choose representative sets from each degree?

Comment: @PyRulez Not if you want the set of indices and the valuation map to be uniformly $\Pi^1_1$ in $X$ ...

Comment: Noah, that is an interesting question. Can you formulate a precise version of the question? You want a notation system that somehow accepts a set $X$ as a parameter, and the order type depends only on the degree of $X$ and not on the particular set? Or do you want the order itself on the terms to depend only on the degree and not on the set? That seems unlikely.

Comment: @Noah, do you want $X:\to \mathcal{N}^X$ to be a $\Pi^1_1$ function or $\mathcal{N}^X$ to be $\Pi^1_1(X)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ordinals of the form $\omega_D^{CK}$, as you denote it, are exactly the [countable admissible ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_ordinal), and these ordinals are intensely studied in the context of admissible set theory and fine structure theory.

Answer (score 4):

This concerns Noah's question. First let me formulate Noah's question more precisely.

> **Question**: Is there a $\Pi^1_1$-degree invariant function $f: 2^{\omega}\to 2^{\omega}$ such that $\forall x\forall y(x\equiv_T
> y\implies f(x)=f(y))$ and for any $x$, $f(x)$ is a $\Pi^1_1(x)$-real
>   coding a well order with order type $\omega_1^{x}$?

The question has a negative answer under $ZF+AD+DC$. First note that  $f$ is uniformly degree invariant function that cannot be a constant at any upper cone of Turing degrees.

Secondly, the following lemma is clear.

> **Lemma**: There is a natural number $n_0$ so that both $A_0=\{x\mid f(x)(n_0)=0\}$ and $A_1=\{y\mid f(x)(n_0)=1\}$ are cofinal in the Turing
>   degrees.
>
> **Proof**: Otherwise, $f$ would be a constant at an upper cone of Turing degrees.

Then $A_0$ and $A_1$ are disjoint cofinal sets of Turing degrees, a contradiction to Martin's result.

Note that to negate the question, a fragment of $PD$ is sufficient. Under full $AD$, it actually shows that there is no such function (not just $\Pi^1_1$) $f$ at all. More precisely, what we actually prove is the following.

> **Theorem:** Assume $ZF+AD+DC$. There is no function $f$ such that $\forall x\forall y(x\equiv_Ty\implies f(x)=f(y))$ and $f(x)$ is not
>   constant at an upper cone of Turing degrees.

At right now I don't know how to negate the question under $ZFC$. But under the assumption $V=L$, it can be proved that there is a $\Pi^1_1$-degree invariant function $f: 2^{\omega}\to 2^{\omega}$ such that $\forall x\forall y(x\equiv_T
y\implies f(x)=f(y))$ and for any $x$, $f(x)$ is a real
 coding a well order with order type $\omega_1^{x}$.